# Making igraph clearer to read

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I have a directed igraph with 69 vertices, shown below. It was plotted using the igraph package:

```
library(igraph)
ig <- graph.adjacency(data, mode="directed", weighted=TRUE) 
plot(ig)
```

I'm looking to achieve the following 2 things:

(a) Space the vertices out and maybe lengthen the edges to make it a little easier to read

(b) In reality, my labels are longer. Is it possible to make a vertex bigger and the text smaller to accommodate this.

Any ideas?

Here is my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtedrd1x1duqllj/data.Rdata?dl=0

[image: igraph]

Comment: Have you tried any of the other graph layout options?

Comment: Which ones would you recommend for something like this?

Comment: Can't tell without your data. There's only 12 layout.* functions in `igraph`. Some have parameters to play with.

Comment: Did you at least try to read through the documentation? igraph's manual is extremely thorough and readable: http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html

Comment: Did read the documentation, still unsure how to space the graph out more?? Will removing empty space through the margin command help?

Comment: You need to provide your data. Upload it somewhere (Dropbox, maybe??) and provide a link in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, have provided a link to my data file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of the parameters are definitely highly customizable. I substituted state names for your vertex labels:

```
# this ensures the starting random position is the same
# for the layouts that use a random starting position
set.seed(1492) 

l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(ig, niter=5000, area=vcount(ig)^4*10)

plot(ig, layout=l, 
     edge.arrow.size=0.5, 
     vertex.label.cex=0.75, 
     vertex.label.family="Helvetica",
     vertex.label.font=2,
     vertex.shape="circle", 
     vertex.size=1, 
     vertex.label.color="black", 
     edge.width=0.5)
```

[image]

You shld rly take some time to read `help("igraph.plotting")` & `help("layout")`

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Sorry for bringing up this old topic, but since version 0.8 `igraph` has deprecated and then removed the `area` attribute, which I suppose was allowing for more space between the nodes (?). Do you know of any replacement for `area`?